# Is there a crowdfunding platform for trips?

Tags: online-resources, money, refunds

I often organise trips with a large group of friends. It is always a pain to get everybody to commit and pay in time to cover the deposits and/or book the tickets. It would be so convenient if it would be possible to let people commit similar to how people commit on a project on [indiegogo](https://www.indiegogo.com/) or [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/).

I was considering using indiegogo to setup a campaing, e.g. Lets go to Paris, and start making reservations once a minimal number of friends paid and committed to the trip. However, Indiegogo aims at reaching as many people as possible, whereas I would like to limit the crowd to very limited inner circle of friends.

Does a crowdfunding platform exist to cover very small travel projects to cover the initial costs? I could of course use the conventional method by letting people commit by transfer the initial funds by wire transfer. However, the beauty of projects like indiegogo, is that people commit and only if a target is reached their credit card is charged. If the target isn't reached, I don't have to deal with all the refunds.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a good question, and It is suprising to verify that this is something that already exists on the web!

I'm talking about the [Kicktraveler](http://www.kicktraveler.com/) platform, "where traveling meets crowdfunding".

As stated in the help section of the website

> Kickraveler is a tavel-crowdfunding platform.  People who want to take
>   a trip and that are looking for other mates to go with, can tell the
>   world their travel program and wait for others to join in. Kickraveler
>   is also a place to discover trips. People who are looking to go to any
>   destination can browse Kicktraveler, pick a trip and join in.

Without copying the whole help section, I just redirect you to the ["how it works" page,](https://kicktraveler.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200101111-How-does-Kicktraveler-work-) then you can easily browse from there.

It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

This is a project which is in its early phase, so that it does not host many travels, but on the other hand it has the enormous advantage that **the platform doesn't charge you with any additional cost.**